# Split list item and show in multiple pages inside table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list with 37 items and I want to show this items in four different pages inside a table.

How can I split those items and show in 4 different pages using `javascript` or `vue.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your own implementation you can filter your list of items and split it into subarrays based on how many items you want in one page. Below is an example code on how to achieve that.

Example component's contents:

```
data() {
   return {
      currentPage: 1,
      itemsPerPage: 3,
      items: [{id: 1, title: 'test1'},{id: 2, title: 'test2'},{id: 3, title: 'test3'},{id: 4, title: 'test4'},{id: 5, title: 'test5'},{id: 6, title: 'test6'},{id: 7, title: 'test7'},{id: 8, title: 'test8'}]
   }
},
computed: {
   paginatedItems() {
      let page = 1;
      return [].concat.apply(
         [], 
         this.items.map( (item, index) => 
            index % this.itemsPerPage ? 
               [] : 
               { page: page++, items: this.items.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage)}
         )
       );
   },
   currentPageItems() {
      let currentPageItems = this.paginatedItems.find(pages => pages.page == this.currentPage);
        return currentPageItems ? currentPageItems.items : [];
   }
},
methods {
   changePage(pageNumber) {
      if(pageNumber !== this.currentPage)
           this.currentPage = pageNumber;
   }
}
```

Example template:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in currentPageItems" :key="item.id">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <span>Page:</span>
    <button v-for="i in paginatedItems.length" class="btn btn-secondary mr-1" :class="{'btn-success' : currentPage === i }" @click="changePage(i)">
      {{i}}
    </button>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/334506/